# Possible to filter messages in rxplot?

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm stuck using a message type that was perhaps poorly designed in that it's been multiplexed. That is to say several different joints are using the same message, but filling out a different joint index. I can't change the message unfortunately, but still need to work with it.

*Is it possible to use rxplot to plot the information in such messages?* I would have to basically set up some sort of conditional plotting.

I'm guessing this is not possible and my best option is to write a little translator node to convert the messages into either different topics or one that aggregates. But figured I'd ask anyway.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29289/possible-to-filter-messages-in-rxplot?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also pipe data with a filter using rostopic like so (one line):

```
rostopic echo --filter "int(m.header.stamp.secs) % 3 == 0" /imu_data/orientation/x | rostopic pub bar std_msgs/Float64
```

This example just publishes messages with a timestamp divisible by 3 to **bar**, but you can put any python expression there (such as to filter by your joint index) and then use:

```
rxplot bar/data
```

to plot it. However the rostopic wiki article warns that filtering give a performance hit, not sure how that would impact your current system.

For more info: [rostopic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_pub)

---

Originally posted by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) with karma: 112 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-03-07**:
Oh, nice. This will work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your filter/translator node is the best option.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1